# How to return the total sum of cells in a loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Please, i need some help with VBA.
I need to do the following.
I want to do a loop and sum every specific cell in previous identified rows. I found the amount off matches that fits with my search, and with this i have a number, lets say "3". I have an multiplication factor of "9".
So, in the column "D" i want to sum every cell that fits it. Ex.: "D9"; "D18", "D27", so on..."
It starts every time in cell "D9" and should increase 1 multiplication factor (9) for every occurrence, in this case, 3.
In the end i want the loop to give me the total sum of these cells.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: How about `=COUNTIF`.

Comment: Fabrizio, sorry i did but didn't post here because it's in portuguese. I can post here. Just a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following for loop:-

```
sum = 0
val = 3
for i = 1 to end
    sum = sum + Range("D" & i * val).value
    val = val + 1
next i;
```

Hope this algorithm can help you.

Comment: I didn't, thanks. I've posted my WRONG code here if you can take a look.

Thanks in advance!